# Why do I get a segmentation fault printing the contents of my linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, stack, malloc

I am trying to implement a stack-esque structure using a linked list in C. Eventually it will read strings of varying length from an input file, thus the need for dynamic memory. I am getting a segmentation fault at the printf in printList and I cannot figure out why. I was also getting segmentation faults in push earlier, but I seem to have fixed them. In case it's not obvious, my intent is to add elements only to the "top" of the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void* emalloc(size_t n);

typedef struct node {
    struct node* next;
    char* word;
} node;

node* head = NULL;

void* emalloc(size_t n) {
    void* p;
    p = malloc(n);
    if(p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}

void push(char* w) {
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = (node*) emalloc(sizeof(node));
        head->word = (char*) emalloc(strlen(w) * sizeof(char) + 1);
        strncpy(head->word, w, strlen(w) + 1);
        printf("Pushed a word to head.");
        return;
    }

    node* newnode = (node*) emalloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->word = (char*) emalloc(strlen(w) * sizeof(char) + 1);
    strncpy(newnode->word, w, strlen(w) + 1);
    newnode->next = head;
    head = newnode;
}

void printList() {
    node* cur = head;
    if(cur == NULL || cur->word == NULL) printf("Whoops!");
    while(cur != NULL) {
        printf(cur->word);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}


/*
 * The encode() function may remain unchanged for A#4.
 */

void main() {
    char word[20] = "Hello world";
    //push("Hello",head);
    //push("World",head);
    //push("!",head);
    push(word);
    printList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why copy to 1 past end of string in push()?  Also, if string is too long, strncpy won't NUL it for you.

The real crash though is in the "Head" creation, the first if statement when no entries exist.   It does not NULL its next pointer so therefore list traversal will will blow up on last entry as it reads a garbage pointer at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me, as michael Dorgan ask why did you 1 byte past the end of the string.

I recomend to use something like :

```
int len =strlen(w)
```

before

```
node* newnode = (node*) emalloc(sizeof(node));
newnode->word = (char*) emalloc(len * sizeof(char));
strncpy(newnode->word, w, len)[len]=0;
newnode->next = head;
```

this temporal variable eliminate the need of use strlen on these locations.